# Youtube - YT Object Has No Method PauseVideo()

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have embedded iFrame Youtube videos onto my page and I want the video to pause when the user clicks on the 'next' button to cycle through the carousels of videos. Before I cycle to the next video, I create a YT Object for the active video and try to run the `pauseVideo()` function. The console reports the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<S> has no method 'pauseVideo'`.

What is puzzling is that I have `console.log` the player before calling the `pauseVideo()` function and I do see the `pauseVideo()` method available in the object. Does anyone have any idea why I am able to see the method in the YT Object, but the console keeps reporting that the method does not exist?

JS-Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WPe9/

```
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously on DOM load
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Triggered when user clicks 'next slide'
pauseActiveYoutubeVideos : function() {                 
    var player = new YT.Player( $('#media .item.active iframe.ytplayer')[0] );
    console.log( player );   //pauseVideo() is defined in this player object
    player.pauseVideo();     //console reports 'Uncaught TypeError: Object #<S> has no method 'pauseVideo''
}
```

Comment: What happens if you force it like this : YT.Player(player).pauseVideo();

Comment: @RomainBraun The video still does not pause. Console reports an odd error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

Comment: Try only sending the ID of the dom element to the YT.Player constructor : `'media .item.active iframe.ytplayer'` , instead of a jQuery object.

Comment: @RomainBraun I still get the same error as before and the video does not pause: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined`.

Comment: Remove the first thing I told you to do

Comment: @RomainBraun Doesn't work: `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<S> has no method 'pauseVideo'`.

Comment: Mmmmh I don't know. Would you care putting your code in a working jsfiddle so I could experiment ?

Comment: Sure, let me simplify my code first. Give me a few min.

Comment: No problem, I won't be home before an hour anyway.

Comment: My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7WPe9/

Comment: I very recently encountered very similar issues with Flowplayer (Flash-based web player library), and with VideoJS's (HTML5 web video library with Flash fallback) Flash fallback. I unfortunately can't find/remember any of my sources for this information to back it up, but I discovered that if a Flash player is considered hidden on the page, the underlying Flash object completely disables its API (guessing security concerns). The API takes a second or so to re-activate the API when shown. Try delaying your pause call until after your video is fully shown to see if this is a similar issue.

Comment: The API appears to be disabled to the point that it hides the existence of API methods, hence the error message.

Comment: I've added a delay of 5 sec, but that did not work.

Comment: Hmm, tried it myself and still got the errors too. In my own project, waiting before pausing seemed to fix it, but that was also using non-iframed (and non-YouTube) Flash objects. I'm pretty certain that the error message still means the API has been hidden/disabled, but obviously it's not from the player being hidden.

Comment: @ajp15243 How would I verify if the API has been hidden/disabled?

Comment: @icu222much I don't recall coming across any "official" way to tell this, other than the fact that normal API calls on a Flash object just result in the kind of message you're getting (i.e. `Object #<SomeFlashObject> has no method 'someApiMethod'`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lots of little things here adding up to your problem. First of all, you have to send in an ID as an argument rather than a jquery object (as pointed out in one of the comments). More importantly, the YT iframe API has trouble when you bind an iFrame to a player object and then remove it ... you can't then rebind to that same iFrame again. So your nested loops need to be replaced. One strategy that generally works is to set up a separate tracking object where you create a YT.Player object for each video right at the beginning, and then just keep track of which one should be the active one (so you know which one to pause). Try something like this (and it should just be in a `<script>` tag, rather than in a jQuery 'ready' function, so as to avoid problems with the iFrame API's asynchronous load):

```
// Load the IFrame Player API code asynchronously on DOM load
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "http://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// Sets up player tracker, and init the carousel
  var players={}, activePlayerId;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        $('iframe.ytplayer').each(function() {
                players[$(this).attr('id')]=new YT.Player($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        activePlayerId=$('iframe.ytplayer').first().attr('id');
        $("#"+activePlayerId).addClass('active');

 // Click on carousel next button
        $('#next').on('click', function() {
                players[activePlayerId].pauseVideo();
                $("#"+activePlayerId).removeClass('active');
                if ($("#"+activePlayerId).next().is('iframe')) {
                        activePlayerId=$("#"+activePlayerId).next().attr('id');
                }
                else {
                        activePlayerId=$('iframe.ytplayer').first().attr('id');
                }
                $("#"+activePlayerId).addClass('active');
        });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you create player object, make sure that 'onReady' event happened before you call 'pauseVideo' method.

For example, you can stop the video this way:

```
        var player = new window.YT.Player(yourIframeElement, {
            events: {
                'onReady': function(event) {
                    event.target.pauseVideo();
                }
            }
        });
```

Notice: if you try to create the object with the same video element again,  'onReady' event won't happen anymore.